# Latest Google Chrome breaking MSE?

Tags: discussion, bug, google-chrome

I just got the latest Google Chrome browser. (Version 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

Here is a screen shot

[image]

Is this a Chrome problem or does this have something to do with the new user interface in the Stack Exchange? Anyone else experiencing this?

Same thing is happening with Meta.

Comment: I don't see it when I open the site with Chrome (same version as you).

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila. May I ask if you are also running Windows 10?

Comment: I just updated my Chrome to 69, and I'm on Windows 10, but I don't have any problem. Meanwhile, looks like [there's a problem with high DPI users on Chrome 69](https://techdows.com/2018/09/google-is-working-to-fix-fonts-blurry-issue-in-chrome-69-update.html) (read further on the bug report and their discussion)